# java HttpsURLConnection

Tags: java, curl

I tried to make this curl request executable from Java:

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/vnd.twitchtv.v2+json' \
-d "channel[status]=testing+some+stuff" \
-X PUT https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/testacc222?oauth_token=6e7b9cyfi8zk1gr8g06eecebnitlcvb
```

My solution looks like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    String uri = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/testacc222?oauth_token=6e7b9cyfi8zk1gr8g06eecebnitlcvb";
    URL url = new URL(uri);

    HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("PUT");
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/vnd.twitchtv.v2+json");

    String data = "channel[status]=testing";
    OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
    out.write(data);
    out.flush();
    for (Entry<String, List<String>> header : conn.getHeaderFields().entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(header.getKey() + "=" + header.getValue());
    }
}
```

I don't see any problem yet all it returns is:

```
Status=[400 Bad Request]
null=[HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request]
Server=[nginx]
X-Request-Id=[ccc7a9a4a327b18ea4bf496f1f314fb8]
X-Runtime=[0.032328]
Connection=[keep-alive]
X-MH-Cache=[appcache1; M]
Date=[Sun, 06 Jul 2014 14:07:49 GMT]
Via=[1.1 varnish]
Accept-Ranges=[bytes]
X-Varnish=[2778442693]
X-UA-Compatible=[IE=Edge,chrome=1]
Cache-Control=[max-age=0, private, must-revalidate]
Vary=[Accept-Encoding]
Content-Length=[83]
Age=[0]
X-API-Version=[2]
Content-Type=[application/json; charset=utf-8]
```

I'm trying to figure this out for over a week now and I just don't see the mistake. Any help whatsoever would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does it work with 'GET' instead of 'PUT'?

Comment: GET requests work yes

Comment: Maybe your server doesn't allow 'PUT' requests. Check the code of your server in this case.

Comment: the curl request works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try examining the response body, as it probably contains details about the rejection.  Since the Content-Type specifies `utf-8`, you can create an InputStreamReader using that:

```
try (Reader response =
    new InputStreamReader(conn.getErrorStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {

    int c;
    while ((c = response.read()) >= 0) {
        System.out.print((char) c);
    }
}
```

**Update:** The response body states that the 'channel' parameter isn't present.  This is because `curl` automatically encodes the POST data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, but your code does not.  You'll need to use URLEncoder on your data and also set the request's Content-Type:

```
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("PUT");
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/vnd.twitchtv.v2+json");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

String data = "channel[status]=testing";
data = URLEncoder.encode(data, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: seems like the same output `Status=[400 Bad Request]
null=[HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request]
Server=[nginx]
X-Request-Id=[2128f11fe37431f0e1e890f130b2b665]
X-Runtime=[0.039659]
Connection=[keep-alive]
X-MH-Cache=[appcache2; M]
Date=[Sun, 06 Jul 2014 14:23:36 GMT]
Via=[1.1 varnish]
Accept-Ranges=[bytes]
X-Varnish=[1208902393]
X-UA-Compatible=[IE=Edge,chrome=1]
Cache-Control=[max-age=0, private, must-revalidate]
Vary=[Accept-Encoding]
Content-Length=[83]
Age=[0]
X-API-Version=[2]
Content-Type=[application/json; charset=utf-8]
`

Comment: That seems unlikely; perhaps it wasn't flushed to standard output.  Try adding a `System.out.println();` after the above code.  The headers indicate that the response body contains 83 bytes of JSON.

Comment: oh my mistake, it returns a IO error `Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/testacc222?oauth_token=6e7b9cyfi8zk1gr8g06eecebnitlcvb
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
 at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
 at testing.twitch.main(twitch.java:31)`

Comment: Try replacing `getInputStream()` with `getErrorStream()`.

Comment: Now it throws a NullPointerException

Comment: Is there any other way to implement this besides HttpsURLConnection?

Comment: You should not be getting a NullPointerException.  When I try it, I get this response body: `{"error":"Bad Request","status":400,"message":"Missing required parameter channel"}`